# Best practices for latencies & timeouts in service-to-service communication

Tags: web-services, service, timeout, microservices, latency

Is there any best practice on how to set *efficient timeouts*?

I've been reading up on several sources, but couldn't quite get an answer for these areas:

1. How does downstream service "Promotions" understand its own latency and communicate appropriate timeouts to the "Relevance" service? I found [this](https://medium.com/@kevanahlquist/a-starting-point-for-setting-timeouts-28079499ba9) source discussing the topic, however I am still confusing in how the latency should be measured: When talking about response times, is this the outgoing *response time* from the callee, or is this the perceived time at the caller?
2. Should it be the callee's responsibility to communicate timeouts or just 99th latency percentiles? I'm thinking of various geographic locations of the caller that will have an impact on the timeout. Assuming "Promotions" service offers one API that returns data within 2ms for 99th percentile. For a caller in the same data center, an appropriate timout might be 20ms, while for a caller in a different data center it might be 150ms.

With setting appropriate timeouts, I hope to avoid having the caller to wait too long (active threads, cascading failures) or wait not long enough (retry too soon).

[image: Service timeouts]